# How to put random characters in between random strings at any position?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, data-structures

I have two lists that are generated automatically in Python (using String and Random). Say I ran the code and currently have them like this:

```
random_word = ['Sirius','July','Seven']
random_char = ['#','$','%']
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
random_list = ['Siriu$s', 'J%uly', 'S#even']
```

*Note 1: The special characters can be positioned either all at the same position or at any random position*

Now, this is the part where I've stopped, because I haven't found a way yet to -*at least*- put the special characters at any specific position in each string of the list `random_word`:

```
for k in random_words:
  for i,j in list(enumerate(random_char)):
    random_list = k.insert(i*2, j)
print(random_list)
```

*Note 2: I know my mistake above, k is a str and can't use the `insert()` (that's the main error I know for now :P). However, I wanted to show my thought of the process of what I initially was attempting to do; putting a random character `j` from `random_char` at the second position `i*2` of the random word without replacing it, using two for loops*

As always any guidance on how to make this right is very well appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one way using `random.randrange` with `random.shuffle`:

```
random_word = ['Sirius','July','Seven']
random_char = ['#','$','%']

random.shuffle(random_char)
for w, c in zip(random_word, random_char):
    i = random.randrange(0, len(w)+1)
    print(w[:i] + c + w[i:])
```

Possible output (since it's random):

```
S#irius
%July
S$even
```

Comment: @Supernova Importantly note the distinction between using `random.shuffle(random_char)` once, or picking three random chars with replacement.